# Is there a difference between "incorrigible" and "inveterate"?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage

Source: Collins Dictionary

Definitions:

> 1. incorrigible:  not corrigible; that cannot be corrected, improved, or reformed, esp. because firmly established, as a habit, or because set in bad habits, as a child

> 2. inveterate: firmly established by long continuance, as a disease, habit, practice, feeling, etc.; chronic

Examples:

> Incorrigible: I was sent to Hennington Hills as banishment for being an incorrigible youth.

> inveterate: Lucien, known as Lucy, is an inveterate liar who isn’t as good at it as he thinks he is.

The only similarity I see between these two words is the notion of someone being forever set in their ways. So what is the difference?

Comment: The difference is given in the definitions; _incorrigible_ = impossible to correct, _inveterate_ = has been that way for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

**Incorrigible** always has a negative connotation. You can't be incorrigible in a good way.

**Inveterate** doesn't have to be negative. It's most often used to describe a habit or a practice that's repeated so much it's not likely to change. But the habit or practice doesn't have to be bad. For example, you can be an inveterate networker.

That said, nobody will know what you mean if you use **inveterate**, at least in American English. It's not a commonly used word.

Comment: That's a bit of an exaggeration; it's not flagged as an archaic word in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inveterate)

Comment: Yeah, but just about anyone I know would have to look it up in the dictionary.